# how do I change the "always on top" detachable compilation results window in Intellij to NOT "always on top"?

Tags: intellij-idea

In Intellij, I prefer the compilation results (from Ctrl+F5) in a separate window rather than as a "panel" of the main IDE window. However, when I drag the compilation results panel to "outside" the main window, the resulting separate window is "always on top".

I would like it to just behave as a regular separate window, without being always on top.

I'm using Intellij IDEA 2023.1.4 ultimate edition, on Fedora 38.

Here's a screenshot of the main window and compilation results window, with the latter on top.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

to turn the separate window into a NON-"always on top" window, click the "gear" options icon in the compilation results window, then go to "view mode". You'll see "Float" selected when the window is "always on top". Instead, select "Window", and it will no longer be "always on top".